# JMeter xpath extractor isn't working

Tags: xpath, jmeter

Say for this effective sample of html

```
<html>
<body>
    <select>
        <option value="123" selected></option>
        <option value="456"></option>
        <option value="789"></option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

In chrome's developer console I wrote this xpath:
`$x('(//select/option)[1]/@value')`
and correctly got
`[value="123"]`

In JMeter 3.0, I placed the same xpath selector (`(//select/option)[1]/@value`), however, I always get the `NOT_FOUND`value. I'm not sure why, but my guess is that perhaps the `/@value` is a dom value? I know that this isn't placed into the dom with front-end javascript (which jmeter doesn't parse), but is returned as html directly from the server.

Perhaps this is just a misunderstanding on my part about what xpath can and cannot do, but in either case I am not sure why my xpath selector isn't working and would like some clarification as to how to get this value via xpath.

Comment: when you enter your xpath in JMeter are you including $x ?

Comment: No, I am not. The only thing in the field is `(//select/option)[1]/@value`

Comment: Try this :-`//select/option[1]/@value`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 problems, one obvious and one possible:

1. Your XPath expression contains one extra `(`, remove it
2. In case if response is not XML/XHTML-compliant you need to use "Tidy" in order to parse it. Check *jmeter.log* file and in case you see something like `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException` - it means that XPath extractor has failed

You can also use "XPath Tester" mode of the View Results Tree listener to debug your XPath expressions on-the-fly

Demo:

[image: XPath Extractor demo]

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) article for comprehensive information on using XPath for correlation in JMeter tests.

Comment: From your first point, I don't see an extra `(`. It is balanced with a `)`? To your second point, that's what I needed to know (I didn't know how to debug xpath information in jmeter, so this was very helpful)

Answer (score 0):

For performance, maintainability and ease I would use [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) instead of XPath.

Where Css expression based on [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) will be:

> option:eq(0)

See:

[image]